# Keep Same Filename When Converting Using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, jpeg2000

I'm trying to convert several hundred specifically named .jp2 files in a directory to .jpg files using ImageMagick from the terminal.

For example, I want A.jp2, B.jp2, C.jp2 to become A.jpg, B.jpg, C.jpg.

I tried the following command:

```
convert *.jp2 *.jpg
```

However, this gave me the following files:

- *-0.jpg
- *-1.jpg
- *-2.jpg
- etc.

How can I keep the names of the original files when I convert them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "mogrify" command

```
mogrify -format jpg *.jp2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the -set and formatting options.

```
convert *.jp2 -set filename:base "%[base]" "%[filename:base].jpg"
```